# Resolving a recursive socket.on("data") call

Tags: node.js, sockets, asynchronous, recursion, async-await

I have a node socket server that needs to receive data more than once during a single `socket.on('data')` call. It's sorta like `socket.on('data')` is running recursively. I think I've just configured this really really wrong, but I don't know enough NodeJS to figure it out.

Here's an example of the issue:

```js
const net = require("net");
const socket = new net.Socket();
const port = process.argv[2];

socket.connect(port, "127.0.0.1", () => {
    // We communicate with another server, always with "type" -> "result" messages.
    socket.write(JSON.stringify({ type: "connect", result: "JavaScript" }));
});

function get_query(query) {
    queryMessage = JSON.stringify({
        type: "query",
        result: query,
    });
    socket.write(queryMessage);
    // This is the critical line that I don't know how to resolve.
    // Right at this point I need wait for another socket.on('data') call
    return socket.giveMeThatQuery()
}

socket.on("data", (data) => {
    let jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    if (jsonData["type"] == "call_func") {
        let funcToCall = func_reg[jsonData["result"]];

        // This will need to call get_query 0-n times, dynamically
        result = funcToCall();

        let finishMessage = JSON.stringify({
            type: "finish_func",
            result,
        });
        socket.write(finishMessage);
    } else if (jsonData["type"] == "query_response") {
        // This has to connect back to get_query somehow?
        // I really have no idea how to approach this.
        // async functions? globals?
        giveDataToQuery()
    }
});

function func1() {
    return "bird"; // some funcs are simple
}

function func2() {
    // some are more complicated
    let data = get_query("Need " + get_query("some data"));
    return "cat" + data;
}

function func3() {
    let data = get_query("Need a value");
    let extra = '';
    if (data == "not good") {
        extra = get_query("Need more data");
    }
    return data + "dog" + extra;
}

var func_reg = { func1, func2, func3};
```

This server is just an example, I can edit or provide more context if it's needed. I suppose if you're looking at this question right after it's posted I can explain more [on the live stream.](https://www.twitch.tv/livefrmhollywood)

Edit: adding an example of using globals and while true (this is how I did it in Python). However, in Python, I also put the entire `funcToCall` execution on another thread, which it doesn't seem like is possible in Node. I'm beginning to think this is actually just impossible, and I need to refactor the entire project design.

```
let CALLBACK = null;

function get_query(query) {
    queryMessage = JSON.stringify({
        type: "query",
        result: query,
    });
    socket.write(queryMessage);
    while (true) {
        if (CALLBACK) {
            let temp = CALLBACK;
            CALLBACK = null;
            return temp;
        }
}

...

    } else if (jsonData["type"] == "query_response") {
        CALLBACK = jsonData["result"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was correct, what I wanted to do was impossible. Node (generally) only has one thread, ever. You can only be waiting in one place at a time. Async threads or callbacks doesn't solve this, since the callback I would need is another `socket.on`, which makes no sense.

The solution is `yield`. This allows me to pause the execution of a function and resume at a later time:

```
function* func2() {
    let data = (yield "Need " + (yield "some data"));
    yield "cat" + data;
    yield 0;
}

function* func3() {
    let data = (yield "Need a value");
    let extra = '';
    if (data == "not good") {
        extra = (yield "Need more data");
    }
    yield data + "dog" + extra;
    yield 0;
}
```

I updated the `server.on` to handle these generator function callbacks and respond differently to the `yield 0;`, which indicates the function has no queries. Here's the final `server.on`.

```
server.on("data", (data) => {
    try {
        let jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        let queryResult= null;
        let queryCode = null;
        if (jsonData["type"] == "call_func") {
            var script = require(jsonData["func_path"]);
            FUNC_ITER = script.reserved_name();
        } else if (jsonData["type"] == "queryResult") {
            queryResult = jsonData["result"];
        }

        queryCode = FUNC_ITER.next(queryResult);

        if (queryCode.value == 0) {
            let finishMessage = JSON.stringify({
                type: "finish_func",
                result: null,
            });
            server.write(finishMessage);
        } else {
            let exeMessage = JSON.stringify({
                type: "queryCode",
                result: queryCode.value,
            });
            server.write(exeMessage);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        crashMessage = JSON.stringify({
            type: "crash",
            result: err.stack,
        });
        server.write(crashMessage);
    }
});
```

And an example of the node files I generated containing the custom functions:

```
function* reserved_name() {
    (yield "return " + String("\"JavaScript concat: " + (yield "value;") + "\"") + ";")
    yield 0;
}

module.exports = { reserved_name };
```

If you're wondering, this is for a language called dit, which can execute code in other languages. There's a Python server that talks to these other languages. [Here's an example I finished last week](https://github.com/ditabase/dits/blob/master/dits/hackathon.dit) which uses Python, Node, and Lua as the guest languages: